# PHP Prepared Statement cannot bind JSON result

Tags: php, json, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am running PHP 5.5.9 and the table I want to query is having a JSON column on a MySQL database running MySQL5.7.19.

When I tried something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT json_column FROM my_table";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){
        echo $row->json_column
    }
}
```

I could see the output like the following:

```
[{json_field: some_data}, {json_field: some_data}]
```

However when I tried with prepared statement query:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT json_column FROM my_table");
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    $stmt->bind_result($res_json);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo $res_json;
    }
}
```

I could see no feedback. I am using prepared statement because I think it is a more secure way against sql injection and I wonder why this has failed. The same query work for other columns that are not in JSON.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try with `while($row = $stmt->fetch()){echo $row['json_column'];}`

Comment: @HosSeinM no that doesnt work